# Sorting using vectors

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program of a stock market where I read from a file and sort with symbols and percent gain/loss. I have completed sorting with symbols but having trouble establishing the percent gain loss. Basically i am instructed to use vectors. We are required to produce the list ordered by percent gain/loss and i need to sort the stock list by this component. However i'm not to physically sort the list by component percent gain/loss; instead provide a logical ordering with respect to this component. 
so basically i added a data member, a vector to hold the indices of the stock list ordered by the component percent gain/loss. i called it array indexByGain. so when i print the list ordered by the percent gain/loss, i use the array indexByGain to print the list. my problem is an i need help on how to start if someone could show me an example or explain on how to go about this i can continue or correct me on my rough draft that will be helpful. below is a rough draft of my code. stockType has to do with the where data is stored from the file.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include "stockType.h"

  class stockListType
   {
     public:
       void sortBySymbols();//sort out symbols and it comiples correctly.
       void sortByGain();
       void printByGain();
       void insert(const stockType& item);
     private:
   vector<int> indexByGain;//declared a vector array indexByGain..
    vector<stockType> list;
   };

     void stockListType::insert(const stockType& item)
    {
       list.push_back(item)//inserts the data from file to vector array.
     }
      //function prints out the gain
     void stockListType::printByGain()
 {
    //my code to print out the gain..
   }
     //function to sort the gain and this is where i am stuck.
      void stockListType::sortGain()
       {

          int i, j, min, maxindex;
          for(i=0;i<list.size();i++)
          {
             min = i;
             for(j=i+1;j<list.size();j++)
               list[maxindex].getPercentage()<list[j].getPercentage();
                 maxindex = j;
                 indexGain.push_back(maxindex);
           }
```

I know I am wrong but am i starting on a good base or totally of. please you could assist me or correct me. Thanks. oh sorry before i forget getPercentage() calculates and returns the percentage gain/loss.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the index and use std::sort:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    struct Data {
        int value;
        int percent;
    };
    typedef std::vector<Data> DataVector;
    typedef DataVector::size_type size_type;
    typedef std::vector<size_type> IndexVector;

    DataVector data { { 1, 1 }, { 2, -2 }, { 3, 3 }, { 4, -4 }, { 5, 5} };
    IndexVector index;
    index.resize(data.size());
    for(size_type i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        index[i] = i;
    }

    struct Less
    {
        const DataVector& data;
        Less(const DataVector& data)
        :   data(data)
        {}

        bool operator () (size_type a, size_type b) {
            return data[a].percent < data[b].percent;
        }
    };
    std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(), Less(data));
    for(size_type i = 0; i < index.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << data[index[i]].value << ": " << data[index[i]].percent << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You may use C++11:

```
std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(),
        [&](size_type a, size_type b) { return data[a].percent < data[b].percent; }
    );
for(auto i: index)
    std::cout << data[i].value << ": " << data[i].percent << std::endl;
```

Comment: Just be aware that std::sort calls the copy constructor of the base element several times.  If performance is degrading, check your copy constructor.

Comment: @cup What 'base element' ?